# Publish a message to Kafka topic from REST controller using Spring Cloud Streams Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I was following this Kafka Streams example at [Tanzu](https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-p3/) where an order request is handled through a REST API which then publishes the request to a Kafka topic. This all works fine. However, I didn't like this publisher wherein it creates a KafkaTemplate.

```
new KafkaTemplate<>(orderJsonSerdeFactoryFunction
         .apply(orderJsonSerde.serializer(), bootstrapServer), true) {{
    setDefaultTopic(orderTopic);
    sendDefault(order.getOrderUuid(), order);
}};
```

I read there is an alternative to this using StreamBridge but cant get it to work. InteractiveQueryService cant find seem to find that order.

**Update 1**

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.kafkastreams.cri</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kafka-streams</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-boot.version>${project.parent.version}</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <layers>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </layers>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8090

spring:
  application.name: kafka-streams
  cloud:
    function.definition: orderStateStoreProcessor
    stream:
      source: supplier
      bindings:
        supplier-out-0.destination: orderStatus
        orderStateStoreProcessor-in-0.destination: orderStatus
        orderStateStoreProcessor-out-0.destination: orderProcess
      kafka.streams:
        bindings:
          orderStateStoreProcessor-in-0.consumer.configuration.application.id: ${spring.application.name}-orderStateStoreProcessor
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092 # just to use it in the service app, Its already 'localhost:9092' by default
          auto-add-partitions: true
          min-partition-count: 6
          state-store-retry:
          max-attempts: 10
          backoff-period: 500
          configuration:
            application.id: ${spring.application.name}
            application.server: localhost:${server.port} # for InteractiveQueryService to describe itself
            state.dir: state-${spring.application.name}-${server.port} # to give a unique dir name in case you run multiple of this app on the same machine
            default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$UUIDSerde
            default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
            commit.interval.ms: 1000
            auto.offset.reset: latest
logging.level.com.scb.cri: debug
```

**OrderController.java**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping("order")
    public Order placeOrder(@RequestBody @NotNull(message = "Invalid Order") Order order) {
        //return orderService.placeOrder().apply(order);
        return orderService.supplier().apply(order);
    }

    @GetMapping("order/status/{orderUuid}")
    public OrderStatus statusCheck(@PathVariable("orderUuid") UUID orderUuid) {
        return orderService.statusCheck().apply(orderUuid);
    }

}
```

**OrderService.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderService implements OrderTopology {

    private final InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;

    private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

    private final Serde<Order> orderJsonSerde;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.bindings.orderStateStoreProcessor-in-0.destination}")
    private String orderTopic;

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    public Function<UUID, OrderStatus> statusCheck() {
        return orderUuid -> {
            final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<UUID, String> store =
                    interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(STATE_STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
            HostInfo hostInfo = interactiveQueryService.getHostInfo(STATE_STORE_NAME, orderUuid, new UUIDSerializer());

            log.debug("key located in: {}", hostInfo);
            if (interactiveQueryService.getCurrentHostInfo().equals(hostInfo)) {
                //get it from current app store
                return OrderStatus.valueOf(Optional.ofNullable(store.get(orderUuid))
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException("Order not found")));
            } else {
                //get it from remote app store
                return new RestTemplate().getForEntity(
                        String.format("%s://%s:%d/order/status/%s", "http", hostInfo.host(), hostInfo.port(), orderUuid)
                        , OrderStatus.class).getBody();
            }
        };
    }

    public Function<Order, Order> placeOrder() {
        return orderIn -> {
            //create an order
            var order = Order.builder()//
                    .itemName(orderIn.getItemName())//
                    .orderUuid(UUID.randomUUID())//
                    .orderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING)//
                    .build();

            //producer
            new KafkaTemplate<>(orderJsonSerdeFactoryFunction
                    .apply(orderJsonSerde.serializer(), bootstrapServer), true) {{
                setDefaultTopic(orderTopic);
                sendDefault(order.getOrderUuid(), order);
            }};
            return order;
        };
    }

    public Function<Order, Order> supplier() {
        return orderIn -> {
            //create an order
            var order = Order.builder()//
                    .itemName(orderIn.getItemName())//
                    .orderUuid(UUID.randomUUID())//
                    .orderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING)//
                    .build();

            log.info("Created this order {}", order);
            streamBridge.send("supplier-out-0", order);
            return order;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<UUID, Order>, KStream<UUID, Order>> orderStateStoreProcessor() {
        return uuidOrderKStream -> {
            KTable<UUID, String> uuidStringKTable = kStreamKTableStringFunction.apply(uuidOrderKStream);
            uuidStringKTable.toStream().foreach((k,v) -> {
                log.info("Received this {} with value {}", k, v);
            });
            //then join the stream with its original stream to keep the flow
            return uuidOrderKStream.leftJoin(uuidStringKTable,
                    (order, status) -> order,
                    Joined.with(Serdes.UUID(), orderJsonSerde, Serdes.String()));
        };
    }

}
```

**OrderTopology.java**

```
public interface OrderTopology {

    Predicate<UUID, Order> isOrderMadePredicate = (k, v) -> v.getOrderStatus().equals(OrderStatus.PENDING);
    Predicate<UUID, Order> isInventoryCheckedPredicate = (k, v) -> v.getOrderStatus().equals(OrderStatus.INVENTORY_CHECKING);
    Predicate<UUID, Order> isShippedPredicate = (k, v) -> v.getOrderStatus().equals(OrderStatus.SHIPPED);

    Function<KStream<UUID, Order>, KTable<UUID, String>> kStreamKTableStringFunction = input -> input
            .groupBy((s, order) -> order.getOrderUuid(), Grouped.with(null, new JsonSerde<>(Order.class, new ObjectMapper())))
            .aggregate(String::new,
                    (s, order, oldStatus) -> order.getOrderStatus().toString(),
                    Materialized.<UUID, String, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(STATE_STORE_NAME)
                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.UUID()).
                            withValueSerde(Serdes.String())
            );

    //Just the min req vars
    BiFunction<Serializer<Order>, String, DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<UUID, Order>> orderJsonSerdeFactoryFunction
            = (orderSerde, bootstrapServer) -> new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
            Map.of(
                    ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer,
                    ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0,
                    ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384,
                    ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1,
                    ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432,
                    ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, UUIDSerializer.class,
                    ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, orderSerde.getClass()));

}
```

**Order.java**

```
@ToString
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private UUID orderUuid;

    @NotBlank
    private String itemName;

    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
}
```

**OrderStatus.java**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum OrderStatus {
    PENDING("PENDING"),
    INVENTORY_CHECKING("INVENTORY_CHECKING"),
    OUT_OF_STOCK("OUT_OF_STOCK"),
    SHIPPED("SHIPPED"),
    CANCELED("CANCELED");

    private final String name;

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

**KafkaStreamApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaStreamApplication {

    final static public String STATE_STORE_NAME = "order-events";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaStreamApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<Order> orderJsonSerde() {
        return new JsonSerde<>(Order.class, new ObjectMapper());
    }

}
```

I am able to publish to the topic *orderStatus* but then cant seem to retrieve it from state store. Some logs here

```
2023-05-19 10:46:59,851  INFO http-nio-8090-exec-2 c.k.c.s.OrderService:95 - Created this order Order(orderUuid=face36d8-da5a-42a4-ac0a-529b495fe171, itemName=Shaver, orderStatus=PENDING)

2023-05-19 10:47:00,697  WARN kafka-streams-orderStateStoreProcessor-a846f8d5-51fa-40f2-9f7d-1025969eebbb-StreamThread-1 o.a.k.s.k.i.KStreamKTableJoin:71 - Skipping record due to null join key or value. key=[null] value=[Order(orderUuid=face36d8-da5a-42a4-ac0a-529b495fe171, itemName=Shaver, orderStatus=PENDING)] topic=[orderStatus] partition=[3] offset=[9]
2023-05-19 10:47:01,937  INFO kafka-streams-orderStateStoreProcessor-a846f8d5-51fa-40f2-9f7d-1025969eebbb-StreamThread-1 c.k.c.s.OrderService:106 - Received this face36d8-da5a-42a4-ac0a-529b495fe171 with value PENDING
```

**Update 2**

I have tried to publish using StreamBridge converting my payload with Key and Value but no luck.

```
public Function<Order, Order> supplier() {
    return orderIn -> {
        //create an order
        var order = Order.builder()
                .itemName(orderIn.getItemName())
                .orderUuid(UUID.randomUUID())
                .orderStatus(OrderStatus.PENDING)
                .build();

        log.info("Created this order {}", order);
        Message<Order> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(order).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, order.getOrderUuid()).build();
        streamBridge.send("supplier-out-0", message);
        return order;
    };
}
```

Comment: Kafka Streams doesn't read from REST API and send to producer. This code is only using Spring Kafka producer template, not Cloud Streams... Can you please share more of your code as a [mcve]? Such as the rest controller itself?

Comment: Provided a minimal reproducible example by updating my question